# Is it possible to fetch EWS mailbox's owner and member details through exchangelib python library or any other python library?

Tags: python, module, outlook, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am using exchangelib to extract all the mail details (like subject, in_reply_to, received time etc.,) . I need to extract the owner and members who has access to the mail box. When I tried to run: `account.delegates` it is failing with **None type object is not iterable**

Can exhangelib extract mailbox's owner and member detail, if not is there any python module which can be used to achieve the goal?

Stack trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-e6c725567a6c> in <module>

----> 1 account.delegates

 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py in delegates(self)

    628         """Returns a list of DelegateUser objects representing the delegates that are set on this account

    629         """

--> 630         return list(GetDelegate(account=self).call(user_ids=None, include_permissions=True))

    631

    632     def __str__(self):

 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\exchangelib\services\get_delegate.py in call(self, user_ids, include_permissions)

     21             **dict(

     22                 mailbox=DLMailbox(email_address=self.account.primary_smtp_address),

---> 23                 include_permissions=include_permissions,

     24             )

     25         ):

 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py in _pool_requests(self, payload_func, items, **kwargs)

    510         results = []

    511         n = 0

--> 512         for chunk in chunkify(items, self.chunk_size):

    513             n += 1

    514             log.debug('Starting %s._get_elements worker %s for %s items', self.__class__.__name__, n, len(chunk))

 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py in chunkify(iterable, chunksize)

    107         # generator, set, map, QuerySet

    108         chunk = []

--> 109         for i in iterable:

    110             chunk.append(i)

    111             if len(chunk) == chunksize:

 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `account.delegates` should be the way to go, but a user does not always have access to this information. Please post the stack trace you get when yo access `account.delegates`.

Comment: Updated the stack trace Erik. @ErikCederstrand

Comment: That looks like an old version of exchangelib. Please upgrade to the latest version.